# How far is the horizon on other planets?

Tags: planets

Specifically, at human eye level -- (like if the planet is larger or smaller).

Does anyone know if this can be described in terms of a formula?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  Please start with the [tour] and look around at the kinds of posts we have here.

Comment: I recomend [The Articule "Distance to the Horizon" by Andrew T. Young at the San Diego State University](http://aty.sdsu.edu/explain/atmos_refr/horizon.html) - It is concise and covers refractions which many articles on the topic disregard. You may also be interested in [Fata Morgana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fata_Morgana_%28mirage%29)

Comment: for people voting too broad - it requires just a formula and it exists, thus the answer need one sentence to answer.

Comment: @MolbOrg All the (current) close votes are because it's off-topic.

Comment: @Azuaron I guess it was one person, just didn't voted to close the question, so haven't seen the numbers. Sure it is school question and it can be googled in 5-10-15 minutes, the only guilt of the question, but not off-topic either :). I guess it could be a help for some writer, they are usually not so steady in math and all that. And I like how the answer shows the beauty of geometry :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Yes.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=distance+to+horizon)

[image: geometry]

The formula, generalizing for planet size, can be found on Wikipedia.

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/157730)

Comment: Did you «Close or flag the question and move on»  as it shows in the post you linked?  I don’t see the question on review queues.

Comment: IIRC flagged posts don't show up for diamond moderators in the review queues until after a while, to give the community a chance to handle the flag first. And while the question might not be great, it's hardly terrible, especially from a newcomer; you, though, should know better what makes a good answer.

Comment: @JDługosz If you believe a question needs to be flagged, please don't answer it; it only encourages people to write bad questions.